# Flutter Drawer Not Navigating Correctly

Tags: navigation, flutter

I'm pretty new to Android / Flutter development.

My app has a drawer with 2 expansion tiles -- when I click on any of the children it always navigates to the last child of that expansion tile.
(That is, book1 has 4 sections. Clicking on any section will navigate to book1 sectionC. Book2 with 3 sections will always navigate to book2 sectionC)

I can't understand why this is happening. Thanks for any advice.

Code below reproduces the problem:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {

  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  final data = buildData();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'App',
      theme: new ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: ServiceView(currentService: data.prayerBooks[0].services[0]),
    );
  }
}

class ServiceView extends StatelessWidget {
  final currentService;

  ServiceView({Key key, @required this.currentService}) : super(key: key);

//  ServiceViewState();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final allPrayerBooks = buildData();

    return new Scaffold (
      drawer: _buildDrawer(allPrayerBooks.prayerBooks),
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(currentService.title),
        actions: <Widget>[

        ],
      ),
//      body: _buildService(context, currentService),
    );
  }

  Drawer _buildDrawer(prayerBooks) {
    return Drawer(

      child: new ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
        new DrawerPrayerBookEntry(context, prayerBooks[index]),
        itemCount: prayerBooks.length,
      ),
    );
  }
}



class DrawerPrayerBookEntry extends StatelessWidget {
  const DrawerPrayerBookEntry(BuildContext context, this.prayerBook);

  final PrayerBook prayerBook;

  Widget _buildTiles(BuildContext context, PrayerBook prayerbook) {
    if (prayerbook.services.isEmpty)
      return new ListTile(title: new Text(prayerbook.title ?? 'No Title'));
    return new ExpansionTile(
      key: new PageStorageKey<PrayerBook>(prayerbook),
      title: new Text(prayerbook.title ?? 'No title'),
      children: _buildServicesTiles(context, prayerbook),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildTiles(context, prayerBook);
  }


  List<Widget> _buildServicesTiles(context, prayerBook) {
    List<Widget> servicesList = [];
    Service serviceName;
    for (serviceName in prayerBook.services) {
      servicesList.add(new ListTile(
        title: new Text(serviceName.title ?? 'No title',),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
          Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return ServiceView(
                currentService: serviceName,
              );
            },
          ));
        },
      ));
    }
    return servicesList;

  }
}


PrayerBooksContainer buildData(){
  return new PrayerBooksContainer(
    [
      new PrayerBook('language','book1', 'book1', [
       new Service('service', 'b1 sA'),
       new Service('service', 'b1 sB'),
       new Service('service', 'b1 sC'),
       new Service('service', 'b1 sD'),

      ]),
      new PrayerBook('language','book2','book2',[
        new Service('service', 'b2 sA'),
        new Service('service', 'b2 sB'),
        new Service('service', 'b2 sC'),
      ]),      
    ],
  );
}


class PrayerBooksContainer extends Object {
  final List<PrayerBook> prayerBooks;

  PrayerBooksContainer(
      this.prayerBooks,
      );

}

class PrayerBook extends Object {
  final String language;
  final String apiName;

  final String title;

  final List<Service> services;

  PrayerBook(
      this.language,
      this.apiName,
      this.title,
      this.services,
      );

}

class Service extends Object  {

  final String apiName;

  final String title;


  Service(
      this.apiName,
      this.title,
      );

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your _buildServicesTiles method:

```dart
List<Widget> _buildServicesTiles(context, prayerBook) {
    List<Widget> servicesList = [];
    //Service serviceName;
    for (var serviceName in prayerBook.services) {
      servicesList.add(new ListTile(
        title: new Text(serviceName.title ?? 'No title',),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
          Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return ServiceView(
                currentService: serviceName,
              );
            },
          ));
        },
      ));
    }
    return servicesList;
  }
```